# Request.Get and Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request

```
function getPageT()
{
    Request.get({url: "https://cardanoexplorer.com/api/blocks/pages/total"}, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.dir(error);
        }
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        var total = body.Right

        return Promise.resolve(total)
    });
}

async function assign() {
    var t = await getPageT()
    console.log(t)
}
```

I would like the code above to print the total value but it comes as undefined because the getPage function does not wait for the request to be resolved.

How can I get the promise out of the Request.get ?

Comment: getPageT isn't returning a Promise, it isn't returning anything actually.

Comment: how about now? even returning a Promise it doesn't give me the total variable

Comment: The return statement is still in the callback, not in the actual function

Comment: but if I take it outside the Request it will not wait for the Request to get resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function need to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) if you want the `await` keyword to actually wait for something to happen:

```
function getPageT()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Request.get({url: "https://cardanoexplorer.com/api/blocks/pages/total"}, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.dir(error)
                reject(error);
            }
            body = JSON.parse(body)
            var total = body.Right

            return resolve(total)
        });
    });
}

async function assign() {
    var t = await getPageT()
    console.log(t)
}
```

Comment: the Request.get() doesn't return anything? I was getting confused that it was giving a promise in some way?

Comment: The `reject()` is unreachable

Comment: @user3755529 `Request.get` might return something but you need an actual `return` statement inside your own function. Without it `Request.get` will return *something* but you never do anything with the result and discard it. It's the same as doing `function foo() { 2 + 2 }` vs `function foo() { return 2 + 2 }`

Comment: @charlietfl you're right as usual, I made the correction. Thanks for the input !

Comment: getPagetT() should be getPageT()

Comment: @user3755529 good catch, thanks !